# Unable to click on multiple buttons for same xpath

Tags: java, button, xpath, selenium-webdriver, element

I am trying to click all the buttons from the webpage which is having same xpath. Not able to click on the links.
Following is my script :

```
 WebElement ParentElement= Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty(Object))); 
                List<WebElement> schedule= ParentElement.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

                for(int i=1;i<schedule.size();i++){
                    schedule.get(i).click();
                    Thread.sleep(5000L);
                }
```

Comment: Is it clicking on the same button? Can you let us know the error message you are getting?

Comment: It is the same Button on Webpage. I have to click 3 times the button. Not getting any error. But not able to click on Button.

Comment: If there is only one button, then the list size will be one and the for loop will be executed only once. Can you share the website url and your requirement, so that we can help you with the scenario ?

Comment: Website : http://www.nyrp.com/ Button name is "Book an Appoinment" and "Book a Mammogram". Identifying the element via cssSelector ".schedule>a>img"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cssSelector for `Book an Appointment` button

```
     .schedule>a[href*!='Mammogram']>img
```

The cssSelector for `Book a Mammogram` button

```
     .schedule>a[href*='Mammogram']>img
```

**Update**

```
   driver.get("http://www.nyrp.com/");
   WebElement ParentElement= driver.findElement(By.className("schedule")); 

      List<WebElement> schedule= ParentElement.findElements
                           (By.xpath("//img[@alt='Schedule an appointment']"));
                    System.out.println(schedule.size());

                    for(int i=0;i<schedule.size();i++)
                             {
                                schedule.get(i).click();
                                Thread.sleep(5000);
                         }
```

Comment: Yes it is working for ".schedule>a[href*='Mammogram']>img"
But I want to click all links from the same webpage

Answer (score 0):

Do you leave the page or change its elements via Javascript when the links are clicked? If so then the first click succeeds and all following clicks fail, because the references stored in `schedule` are invalidated.

You have to do a `findElement` before each "click" to get a fresh reference. 
(This also applies for all other actions with such WebElements. Usually you get a StaleElementReferenceException in these cases)

**Edit:** As addition to HemChes answer: 
You already select the buttons with the cssSelector for `ParentElement`, but then search for a-tags inside the first result. Try the following code:

```
List<WebElement> schedule= getDriver().findElements(By.cssSelector(".schedule>a>img"));

for(int i=0;i<schedule.size();i++){
    schedule.get(i).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
}
```

**Edit 2:** fixed c&p error and loop counter

(Assuming `OR.getProperty(Object)` returns the css selector you mentioned in your comment)

Comment: No, for the first time also the Button is not clicked.

Comment: No, it is still not working.
I have also tried to fetch the Object in loop, still facing same issue.
    'WebElement ParentElement= Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty(Object))); 
     List<WebElement> schedule= ParentElement.findElements(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty(Object))); 
      for(int i=1;i<schedule.size();i++){
         schedule.get(i).getAttribute(Object);      
         schedule.get(i).click();
         Thread.sleep(5000L);
          }'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't execute the code before posting - fixed the copy&paste error. The code above runs and clicks on all three buttons.